# Build fails on first attempt then passes

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, build

I have a solution with many projects and 2 of them are a `Webservice` and a `ConsoleApplication`. `Webservice` is the start up project in solution. My solution build order is as follows

1. ProjectA
2. ProjectB
3. ConsoleApplication
4. Webservice

ProjectA and ProjectB are referenced in both the projects. Now when I clean my solution and try to build the solution it fails for the first time. The error comes constructor of a class in ConsoleApplication project where I am instantiating XYZ class of ProjectA. Error is

`The type 'XYZ' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ProjectA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. ProjectPath\Program.cs`

However when I build the solution again it builds successfully. Can anyone help me to understand the behavior. It is not lethal for my project in any way but I don't want Visual Studio to decide when to do what. I want to know the reason for this behavior.

Also, when I build the solution for first time I could see no `.dll` of ProjectA or ProjectB in debug folder of ConsoleApplication. However on second attempt these dlls are visible in debug folder and build succeeds.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: How do the projects reference each other?  This sounds like behavior you might see if you reference the output `.dll` of a project instead of the project itself.

Comment: Are you using Project References or are you referencing ProjectA and ProjectB by filename?

Comment: Sounds like the build order is slightly out of whack and it tries to build ProjectA at the same time as ConsoleApplication. Since ConsoleApplication builds before ProjectA is complete, it fails. The second time you run it, ProjectA has been built and things pass.

Comment: @David: I am referencing Projects and not dlls.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @Sandy Disregarding the build order setting, if you go into "Project Dependencies" of ConsoleApplication, is there a dependency set to ProjectA?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - Yes there is.

Comment: @Sandy did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: Its quite old question. Sorry I don't remember much about it.

Answer (score 3):

Typically that's a build order problem... On your solution do **right click** and go to Build Order.

Then set the correct project build order.

[image: Build Order]

Cheers

Comment: I have mentioned the build order in my question and to me it seems correct. Could you tell me what should be the build order here?

Comment: Sorry about that. Do you have any other third party dll being referenced in ProjectA?

Comment: Yes. I have referenced a outside dll created by me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have not set up project dependencies. You'll have to set up the build dependencies correctly, i.e.

1. Webservice depends ProjectA and ProjectB
2. Console Application depends on ProjectA, ProjectB and Webservice

It's important to make the console depend on the webservice, cause only then the webservice will be guaranteed to be built before the console Application.

For Visual Studio 2012 do, right click your solution > Properties > Project Dependencies >

Comment: Your second point is invalid. Webservice is referencing Console application in my solution. I think my build order should convey that :)